# React-Bootstrap and Bootstrap-sass modal.scss not loading

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I have a react application, which uses react-bootstrap + bootstrap-sass.

I´m loading the bootstrap.scss file in my main app.scss like this:

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap';
```

In my page, I implemented a simple  Component from React-Bootstrap.

But the modal window has no CSS whatsoever, so it looks really bad.

I´ve tried to load the modal.scss directly

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_modals';
```

But still no styles are applied. 
(the modal appears and hides as expected though).

Bootstrap scss is loaded though, as the styles on buttons, dropdowns, etc is present.

Answer (score 1):

You you need to import the compiled CSS into the component JSX files that it applies to.